# no Data displayed in my Listview Widget

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I want to create a `ListView` widget that displays an `ArrayList` of data in the widget....

I've spent a very long time trying to add the `ListView` to the widget, but it added without any data displayed.

Although my data is fetching successfully between classes when I add breakpoints

I don't know what the problem is...

These are my classes:

### **First class (BakingAppWidgetProvider):**

```js
package com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.BuildConfig;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.MainActivity;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Model.Ingredient;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.R;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class BakingAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    public static Ingredient[] mIngredients;
    public  ArrayList<Ingredient> parcelables;
    public static ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients1= new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";
    private static final String TAG = "WidgetProvider";

    public BakingAppWidgetProvider()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
        if(bundle != null) {
            parcelables = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) bundle.getSerializable("INGREDIENTS");
            ingredients1.addAll(parcelables);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"nuuuuuuuul",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        intent.setAction(WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION);
        if (BakingAppWidgetProvider.WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(BakingAppWidgetProvider.TAG, "onReceive "
                        + BakingAppWidgetProvider.WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION);
            final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);
            final ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(
                    context.getPackageName(), BakingAppWidgetProvider.class.getName());
            final int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager
                    .getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
    }

    /**
     * method will update the ListView each time the user opens the IngredientsActivity,
     * meaning that the widget will always show the last IngredientsActivity Ingredients[] that the user seen.
     * @param context app context
     * @param appWidgetManager  app WidgetManger
     * @param appWidgetIds ids which will be updated
     * @param ingredients the ingredients that will fill the ListView
     *
     */
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetIds[], Ingredient[] ingredients)
    {
        mIngredients = ingredients;
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, listViewsService.class);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.baking_app_widget_provider);
            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.list_view_widget, intent);
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, BakingAppWidgetProvider.class);
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.list_view_widget);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(component, views);
        }
    }

    /**
     * the widget will update itself each time the IngredientsActivity will open,meaning that this method
     * is unnecessary in our implementation.
     * @param context app context
     * @param appWidgetManager the application WidgetManager
     * @param appWidgetIds ids which will be updated
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(BakingAppWidgetProvider.TAG, "onUpdate");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,WidgetUpdateService.class);
        Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
        args1.putSerializable("INGREDIENTS",parcelables);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args1);
        context.sendBroadcast(serviceIntent);
        serviceIntent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    { }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    { }




}
```

### the second class (WidgetUpdateService):

```js
package com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Widget;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.MainActivity;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Model.Ingredient;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Model.Step;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WidgetUpdateService extends IntentService
{
    public static final String WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";
    private Ingredient[]mIngredients;
    ArrayList<Ingredient> parcelable = new ArrayList<>();


    public WidgetUpdateService()
    {
        super("WidgetUpdateService");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent( Intent intent)
    {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals(WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION)) {

            final Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
            parcelable =(ArrayList<Ingredient>) bundle.getSerializable("INGREDIENTS");

            if (parcelable != null)
            {
                mIngredients = new Ingredient[parcelable.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < parcelable.size(); i++)
                {
                    mIngredients[i] = (Ingredient) parcelable.get(i);
                }
            }


            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, BakingAppWidgetProvider.class));
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            BakingAppWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(this, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds,mIngredients);
       }
    }
}
```

### the third class (listViewsService) :

```js
package com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.Model.Ingredient;
import com.example.android.advancebakingapp.R;

public class listViewsService extends RemoteViewsService
{
    public static final String TAG = "ListViewsService";


    /**
     * @param intent intent that triggered this service
     * @return new ListViewsFactory Object with the appropriate implementation
     */
    public ListViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent)
    {
        return new ListViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext());
    }
}

class ListViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory
{
    private Context mContext;
    private Ingredient[] mIngredients;

    public ListViewsFactory(Context mContext)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        mIngredients = BakingAppWidgetProvider.mIngredients;


    }

    //Very Important,this is the place where the data is being changed each time by the adapter.
    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged()
    {

        mIngredients = BakingAppWidgetProvider.mIngredients;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (mIngredients == null)
            return 0;
        return mIngredients.length;
    }

    /**
     * @param position position of current view in the ListView
     * @return a new RemoteViews object that will be one of many in the ListView
     */
    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
    {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.baking_app_widget_ingrediant);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_recipe_widget, mIngredients[position].getIngredient());
        return views;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and These are my Layouts:

### baking_app_widget_provider.xml:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#09C"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widgetBodyMarginTop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### baking_app_widget_ingrediant.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widgetPadding"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_recipe_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if onDataSetChanged() is called?
Have you declared the RemoteViews service in the manifest with the following permission ?

android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"

Comment: Yes I added the permission to: service : android:name=".Widget.listViewsService"
and the onDataSetChanged is called successfully but the data of (mIngredients) in this method is null: mIngredients = BakingAppWidgetProvider.mIngredients

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not using static variables like in this case:

```
mIngredients = BakingAppWidgetProvider.mIngredients;
```

What I did was passing the data to the remote adapter, using the intent putExtra method and then extract the data from the intent in my listViewsService. Test your listViewsService code with some dummy data and verify if it's shown in the widget. If you can see the dummy data, then your listViewsService code is correct and you need to check the source of the data, in this case, the value of the static variable which I think is the reason of the problem. Let me know if this helps. Best of luck.